# ruby multiple connections and dns queries

Tags: ruby, dns, net-http

```
http = Net::HTTP.new("hostname", 80)
http.open_timeout = 300
http.read_timeout = 300

pagereq = lambda {
    http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(page, {"User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0"})).body }

some_conditions.to_a.each do |n|

    page = "startpage"+n.to_s

    pagereq.call.scan(/criteria1/).each do |m|
        page = "/"+m.to_s
        puts pagereq.call.scan(/criteria2/)
    end

end
```

I use this template to collect links or something else from sites. It produce DNS resolving on each connection and this is not good.

What I interest in. Resolve hostname one time, make connection, make all operations, close connection.

Answer (score 0):

Mechanize uses persistent http connnections and makes it easier to get the links:

```
require 'mechanize'
@agent = Mechanize.new
@agent.user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0'
page = @agent.get 'http://www.google.com/'
puts page.links.map &:href
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this library.

But it is still interest - optimize 'pure' Net::HTTP.